Оформление вставных конструкций при наличии (1) вводного слова и (2) обращения
Рассмотрим два предложения:
(1) Конечно(?) и это понятно (?) работы будет много.
(2) Товарищи(?)  от этого обращения он никак не мог избавиться(?)  прошу всех приступить к работе.
Как оформить вставные конструкции в этих предложениях и объяснить постановку запятых. Мне кажется, что оформление должно быть одинаковое, но я не уверена.  Помнится, на форуме обсуждалось похожее предложение с вводным словом, а здесь еще интересен вариант с обращением.
Дополнение
Меня в этой теме интересует оформление запятыми и тире. В вопросе я привела схемы предложений, но сейчас нашла реальные примеры с форума (вводное слово)  и из книги (обращение).
Предложения:
(1) Разумеется, — и это очевидно — между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия.
(2) – Товарищи, – это обращение Супермен подцепил в Думе, как вирусную инфекцию, и всё никак не мог вылечиться, – прошу разойтись по местам и приступить к работе.
Ответ на форуме был принят, но мне он непонятен. Я считаю, что вставка относится к вводному слову (поясняет его), и тогда надо ставить вторую запятую, а не первую. Можно сравнить: Нет сомнений, так как это очевидно: между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия. И интонационно эта единая конструкция.
Но сейчас мне не нравятся оба варианта, они выглядят неестественно, в том числе графика. Странно видеть отсутствие запятой после вводного слова, также странно выглядит вставка, если поставить только первую запятую (структура получается необозначенной). Возможно, надо ставить обе запятые (после вводного слова, а также закрыть вставку):
Разумеется, — и это очевидно, — между человеком и животными есть и принципиальные различия. Именно такое симметричное оформление приведено  в примере с обращением.
Но это хотелось бы увидеть в правилах или в нескольких примерах из литературы. А иначе вопрос не будет окончательно решен в пользу того или другого варианта. С другой стороны, вариант не частотный, найти не так просто.
P.S. У Розенталя есть интересный пример на похожую тему. Там обособление второго приложения оформлено как вставка (два тире и одна запятая). Приложение поясняет другое приложение: Все м ы, воспитатели — учителя и родители, — должны учитывать возрастные особенности в общении с детьми.

Шарон, действительно, Хай Дзяо прав насчёт первой вставной конструкции. Что касается второй вставной конструкции, в известных нам справочниках такие предложения не встречаются. Поэтому лучше всего оформить скобками. Ну если вас интересует именно тире и запятые, я посмотрю ещё в одном справочнике. Я вам о нем писал в прошлой теме о в равных конструкциях.

Я посмотрел в том справочнике. Подобных примеров там нет.

Там сказано, что развернутые вставки чаще выделяются скобками. Поэтому вариант со скобками представляется наиболее удачным.

Серж, меня в этой теме интересует не КОНКРЕТИКА двух предложений,  а общий аспект: как оформлять структуры,  которые  не входят в состав предложения (вводные слова, обращения).  Есть два примера из реальных текстов, оба весьма сомнительные.  В обоих оформление тире, а не скобками.  Скобки тоже не всегда хороши, некоторые писатели их категорически не приемлют. Вероятно, решение этой задачи надо искать в литературе и практических примерах. Так что вопрос остается ОТКРЫТЫМ, желательна дополнительная информация из источников.

Шарон,скобки употребляются на равне с тире. Но если с тире, то так: товарищи, — от этого обращения он никак не мог избавиться, — прошу всех приступить к работе.

Короче говоря, в варианте с обращением скобки абсолютно предпочтительны.

Товарищи (от этого обращения он никак не мог избавиться), прошу всех приступить к работе.

Мало на памяти примеров, в которых вставка при обращениии выдеялась бы тире. Трудно найти такие примеры.

Что до другого случая, то можно в качестве альтернативного мнения предположить, что вставка "и это понятно" тесно спаивается со вводным словом "конечно" не только по интонации, но и по смыслу. "Конечно" - это модальное значение уверенности, да и  "и это понятно" тоже в общем-то уверенность.
То есть два слова со значение уверенности спаиваются по сути в единую вводную группу, причём "и это понятно" как бы усиливает "конечно", добавляя к высказанной уверенности такую "пущую" уверенность.
Зачем тогда "и это понятно" вообще считать в данных условиях вставкой? Может, под влиянием "конечно", раз это теперь единая смысловая группа, конструкция "и это понятно" сама преобразуется во вводную?
Если это так, то это просто два вводных слова рядом друг с другом, они разделяются запятой, а скобочки или тире вообще не нужны.

Конечно, и это понятно, работы будет много.

Но нам хочется считать "и это понятно" именно вставкой?
Хорошо, пусть будет вставка, пусть она даже относится к "конечно" - тогда ставим тире, как и нужно при вставке, однако первое тире не будут поглощать запятую, отгородившую вводное слово.

Конечно, - и это понятно - работы будет много.

А для парралелизма и симметричности можно запятую и после второго тире поставить.

Конечно, - и это понятно, - работы будет много.

Надо решить, к чему относится вставка. Если она усиливает "конечно", то вышеприведённая пунктуация сгодится. Если она относится к "работы будет много", то я бы её взял в скобки и поставил в конец этого предложения.

Знаки препинания, которые стоят на месте «разрыва» предложения вставной конструкцией, выделяемой скобками, помещаются после скобок. Когда вставная конструкция явно относится ко второй части предложения, внутри которой она находится, нужный знак препинания перед открывающей скобкой сохраняется.
То есть, две схемы:
А1 (вставная конструкция), А2.
или
А1, (вставная конструкция) А2.

Следовательно:

Товарищи (от этого обращения он никак не мог избавиться), прошу всех приступить к работе.

Реализация схемы:  А1 (вставная конструкция), А2.

В первом примере, следуя этой логике, получаем:

Конечно, (и это понятно) работы будет много.

Реализация схемы А1, (вставная конструкция) А2.

Вот тут есть от чего запнуться и впасть в замешательство. Странновато выглядит такое пунктуационное оформление, да и сама структура предложения. По смыслу "и это понятно" вряд ли относится ко вводному слову "конечно". Ведь понятно не то, что конечно, а то, что работы будет много.
Однако по интонации "и это понятно", скорее всего, испытывает большее тяготение к "конечно", нежели к "работы будет много". Трудновато и вроде как не совсем естественно будет сказать "конечно", потом сделать паузу и произносить остальное.
Короче, сложность ситуации (и пунктуации), по-видимому, заключается в том, что вставная конструкция интонационно ближе к "конечно", а по значение к "работы будет много".
Чтобы не толочь воду в ступе и не осложнять человечеству жизнь, я бы переделал структуру предложения либо сам лексический состав, сделал бы так:

Конечно, работы будет много, и это понятно.  (сложносочинённое предложение)

Конечно, работы будет много, что понятно. (придаточное присоединительное)

Конечно, работы будет много (и это понятно). (вставная конструкция, но не на стыке фрагментов, а в постпозиции к конструкции-"хозяину", что снимает любые двусмысленности)

Конечно, понятно, что работы будет много. (понятно в роли главного предложения)



Спасибо за ответ, голос от меня. Я имела в виду оформление вставки с помощью запятых и тире, но вариант со скобками тоже интересен. Значит, вы считаете, что вставка по смыслу не относится к вводному слову? Я вот думаю, что вводное слово и вставка образуют единую конструкцию со значением авторской точки зрения в начале предложения. А затем следует основная часть, что видно и по интонации (смысл и интонация обычно не противоречат друг другу). Вы не могли бы добавить в ответ вариант оформления вставки запятой и тире?
